# Evaluation of an integral

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

How would one prove that:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\ln (1+\cos \theta)}{\cos \theta}\, {\rm d}\theta= \frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

This is what I did.

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\ln \left ( 1+\cos \theta \right )}{\cos \theta}\, {\rm d}\theta &= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\cos \theta} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1} \cos^n \theta}{n} \, {\rm d}\theta \\ 
 &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^{n-1}\theta \, {\rm d}\theta\\ 
 &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n}{\rm B}\left ( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{n}{2} \right )
\end{align*}

No clue how to proceed. I am also interest in seeing another approach that does not use Taylor expansion.

Comment: Are you familiar with Residue calculus?

Comment: I am ... what is your suggestion?

Comment: Just an idea.. since you have $\cos$ in you integral, what about taking the $\Re(e^{i\theta})$ and see what happens? Repeat: just an idea, I should try too but I have no way to do it now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I give some steps here, and I leave it to you to fill in the details.

Start with
$$
f(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\ln(1+a \cos \theta)}{\cos\theta}\,d\theta.
$$
Then
$$
f'(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+a\cos \theta}\,d\theta=\cdots=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\arctan\Bigl(\frac{\sqrt{1-a}}{\sqrt{1+a}}\Bigr)
$$
Integrating, we find that
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(a)&=f(0)+\int_0^af'(\theta)\,d\theta=0+\Bigl[-2\Bigl\{\arctan\Bigl(\frac{\sqrt{1-\theta}}{\sqrt{1+\theta}}\Bigr)\Bigr\}^2\Bigr]_0^a\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{8}-2\Bigl\{\arctan\Bigl(\frac{\sqrt{1-a}}{\sqrt{1+a}}\Bigr)\Bigr\}^2.
\end{aligned}
$$
In particular
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\ln(1+ \cos \theta)}{\cos\theta}\,d\theta=f(1)=\frac{\pi^2}{8}.
$$

Comment: Thanks... I can do the details... (+1)!