# Where did I make a mistake while integrating?

Tags: integration

For the integral

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\pi} \sec x \ln(1 + \cos x) dx $$

I separated it into

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} $$

and substituted $x \mapsto x - \frac{\pi}{2}$ on the second integral. Since $\cos \left( x - \frac{\pi}{2} \right) = \sin x$ we have

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sec x \ln(1 + \cos x) dx + \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \csc x \ln(1 + \sin x) dx $$

Now let $x \mapsto \frac{\pi}{2} - x$ on the second integral then

$$ I = 2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sec x \ln(1 + \cos x) dx $$

However, Wolfram seems to disagree with this identity as it approximately gives $4$ as the coefficient, not $2$. (Wolfram could not evaluate both integrals exactly, but the approximate answer shows $4$.)

1. Where did I make a mistake? Or is Wolfram wrong? (Since I don't have Maple, Mathematica, etc. to test on another CAS)
2. How do you evaluate $I$? I'm pretty sure it has a simple closed form since it's from a Math contest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate $\int_0^\pi\frac{\ln\left(1+\cos\theta\right)}{\cos\theta}\,d\theta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2387130/evaluate-int-0-pi-frac-ln-left1-cos-theta-right-cos-theta-d-theta) (found using [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz))

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist That answers my second question but I still have no idea where I made a mistake.

Comment: Your substitution is $u=x-\pi/2$ therefore $\cos(x)=\cos(u+\pi/2)=-\sin(u)$ you confused yourself by trying to keep the same dummy variable.

Comment: @zwim I see. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's kind of nice to keep the same variable $x$, doing a substitution like $x \mapsto x - \frac{\pi}{2}$ risks confusing the "old $x$" and "new $x$". Doing your first transformation more carefully changing to $u$ instead:

$$ I_2 = \int_{\pi/2}^\pi \sec x \ln(1+\cos x)\, dx $$

$x = u - \frac{\pi}{2}$ gives $dx = du$. When $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, $u=\pi$. When $x=\pi$, $u=3\pi/2$. So

$$ I_2 = \int_\pi^{3\pi/2} \csc u \ln(1 + \sin u)\, du $$

Oops: A translation of the variable in one direction "moves" the integral's bounds in the opposite direction. To get the same bounds, we would need $x = u + \frac{\pi}{2}$:

$$ I_2 = - \int_0^{\pi/2} \csc u \ln(1-\sin u)\, du $$
$$ I_2 = - \int_0^{\pi/2} \sec u \ln(1-\cos u)\, du $$

The two halves aren't so nicely comparable. Though if we think about the behavior of the integrand, we see $\sec x$ has a positive region then a symmetric negative region. But $(1+\cos x)$ decreases from $2$ to $1$ then from $1$ to $0$, and the $\ln$ of those values are quite different, so the function doesn't have a nice symmetry which would double or cancel.

For finding the exact value, see [Evaluate $\int_0^\pi\frac{\ln\left(1+\cos\theta\right)}{\cos\theta}\,d\theta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2387130/) (thanks @Amateur_Algebraist for putting this in the comments).